# Document Map and Print View at the same time

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

My docx document has pictures, the best way to see them is in print view.
I also tent to use Document Map to jump quickly to a section.

In word 2003 and earlier it was possible to see both the print view together with Document Map.
THe new word 2007 does not allow that. If in print view I activate Document Map - I am also switched to Draft view.

**Is there a way to see both - Document Map and use the Print View?**

Comment: interestingly, this problem occurs only sometimes. Not always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem occurs only when you do it via keyboard shortcuts. if you use mouse and the ribon it is OK.